# QGIS Print Composer grid - curved latitude lines

Tags: qgis, print-composer

QGIS 2.8.1

I am preparing a map of the North Atlantic and Arctic Regions in EPSG:3996 IBCAO North Polar Stereographic to display the geometries closer to their shape and size.

In Print Composer, I add a solid grid type in CRS EPSG:4326 to the map item. Interval units as Map units, Interval as 10 (degrees).

The problem is, that the latitude lines becomes a little jagged, and do not curve along the globe.

I've tried changed the CRS of the map to EPSG:3574 North Pole LAEA Atlantic, UTM and others. I have to stick to polar projections and include the North Pole - which often causes problems.

Usually it is a minor problem for everyday tasks, but this time it is a bit more serious as the map I prepare large and would be many years in the largest meeting room of the Government of Greenland, where ambassadors, presidents, kings and queens might drop by...

Question: Is there an issue ticket on this problem in QGIS Print Composer?

My workaround has been:

1. create a grid: Menu Vector -> Research Tools -> Vector Grid...: define extent to X Min=-180, X Max=180, Y Min=0.0 and Y Max=90 (I only needed from Equator and northwards.
2. Densify geomtries: menu Vector -> Geometry tools -> Densify Geometries...: Write the number of vertices to add (more than 1).

It is necessary to densify particularly the latitude lines as they "disappear" in reprojection OTF.

It might be needed to select only latitude lines and run the densify again with a larger number of vertices added.

[image: Latitude lines is not curved]

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I'm setting up a map in Canada Lambert Conformal Conic and getting the same jagged grid lines.

Comment: the solution is mentioned in the question - densify the lines.