# Graticules on Mollweide projection in QGIS layout

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, mollweide

I am trying to prepare a layout in QGIS of a world map, projected in the Mollweide World projection ("ESRI:54009"). When I add a grid, and set the grid CRS to "Default CRS EPSG:4326" I expected to get graticules. However the result as below looks wrong. It's just a cartesian grid overlaid on the layout. [image: figure 1 - QGIS Mollweide]

If I create a similar map in R (with the `tmap` package), and add graticules, I get what looks correct as in the result below [image: figure 2- R Molleweide]

Is it possible to get a graticules grid over the Molleweide projection in a QGIS layout?

Comment: I recommend you to use the "Build Globe view" plugin to generate the graticules as a vector layer, it handles "ESRI:54009" fine.

Comment: You can also follow the workaround in this post : https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/137297/93097 (just put a great densify vertices number ( > 100).

Comment: It works but I did not mention it because even with densification, it's not easy to have the outer circle show properly (at least I did not manage when trying), whereas the plugins makes is really easy

Answer (score 1):

You can create such a grid using QGIS expressions with Geometry Generator or Geometry by expression. Create a layer in EPSG:4326 (e.g. a point layer with one feature set to invisible), then apply the expression from below, where `10` (line 3) is the interval (in degrees) between the lat/lon lines.

[image]

##### Expression to create lat/lon grid

```
with_variable (
    'interval',
    10, -- change interval here
    union (
    collect_geometries(
        array_foreach (
            generate_series(-180, 180, @interval),
            densify_by_count( 
                make_line (
                    make_point (@element,90),
                    make_point (@element,-90)
                ), 
                1000
            )
        )
    ),
    collect_geometries(
    array_foreach (
        generate_series(-90, 90, @interval),
        densify_by_count( 
            make_line (
                make_point (-180,@element),
                make_point (180,@element)
            ), 
            1000
        )
    )
)))
```

Comment: Thanks! I could not get what I wanted with the "Global Builder" plugin suggested by Kasper. The densify option worked fine, as J. Monticolo said. However the outer circle did not appear at both sides (Kasper's comment). I didn't try Babel's suggestion yet, (next week...)